# ReferenceError: $ is not defined yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Adding a javascript inside my view results in the `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. I assume that the problem is due to Yii2 injects scripts last on my page. How to fix this?

**Or how will I prevent Yii2 from autoloading the script files?**

My view

```
  <?php

   use yii\helpers\Html;
   use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
   use yii\helpers\UrlManager;
   use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
   use backend\controllers\StandardController;

   use backend\models\standard;


   ?>

 <div class="domain-form">

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?php



    <?= $form->field($model, 'clause')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

   </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready( function () {
    alert("hi");
    });</script>
```

I need to get this simple script to show an alert after the page loaded. I hav'nt called any of the script file here since yii loads automatically(i think) in the layout by calling

```
  AppAsset::register($this);
```

This results in script files to be registered at the end of the page,after my custom script.

How to solve this?

Comment: This error basically means that at the time of interpreting your javascript inside your view jQuery wasn't loaded. There are multiple ways to solve the problem, but can you first show some of your view and controller code so that I will be able to help you in your case.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Yii2 injects scripts (jquery and the like) last on your page. This is intended and desired. But it means that the jQuery will load AFTER your script, so when your script runs, jQuery does not yet exist.

The easiest way for quick testing is to move yii-scripts (jquery and the like) to the head of the page. Modify `assets\AppAsset.php` and add this:

```
public $jsOptions = array(
    'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD
);
```

Done!

---

But in production you usually want the scripts to load last, and instead you let Yii2 handle your javascript:

```
$this->registerJs(
    '$("document").ready(function(){ alert("hi"); });'
);
```

Now Yii will handle this js and place it after anything important (like jQuery).

You'll however soon notice that IDE's are usually bad at handling this kind of language nesting (JavaScript inside PHP) so the syntax highlighting is likely to break. One way to solve it is to register your script in a separate file:

```
$this->registerJsFile( 'myScript.js' );
```

If you want even more control about which order to load your scripts, you can add dependencies as your second argument, and additional options as the third:

```
$this->registerJsFile( 
    'myScript.js', 
    ['\backend\assets\AppAsset'],  
    ['position' => '\yii\web\View::POS_END']
);
```

If you for some reason absolutely want the script to be rendered inline you can do:

```
$this->registerJs( $this->renderPartial('myScript.js') );
```

---

The recommended way to add your scripts is to use [AssetBundles](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/assets.md). 
Look in `assets/AppAssets.php` and add your js-file to the $js-array.

Comment: Thank you ippi.Class 'backend\assets\View' not found error on adding 'public $jsOptions = array(
    'position' => View::POS_HEAD
);' to the AppAsset.php

Comment: `use yii\web\View;` or `'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD'`. I'm sorry I missed it but any competent IDE will do this stuff for you.

Comment: The code snippet with position is wrong. As of Yii 2.0.6 it should be like

    `$this->registerJsFile('/js/map.js',
        [
            'depends' => ['\yii\web\JqueryAsset'],
            'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_END,
        ],
        'frontendMapJs');`

Comment: what is this $this here @ippi? Is it an instance of yii\web\View?

Comment: @RameshPareek Good question. This was a few years ago when Yii2 was still in beta. I haven't looked at it since then, and looking at it now I honestly can't tell. Sorry! I'm assuming this answer is outdated, as Iilya says.

Comment: figured it out myself. Yes it is an instance of yii\web\View.. :) And I don't think your answer is outdated! it still works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need some assets for a library specific use, register them in the view file like this:

```
use yii\web\JqueryAsset;
JqueryAsset::register(this);
```

Alternatively, if you add `yii\web\JqueryAsset` to your `$depends` attribute inside `AppAsset`, the asset will be loaded automatically for all your views, given that you registered it in the main layout (by default in Yii2 boilerplate).

I wanted to use the yii2-date-range from kartik-v in my project, and did this:

```
use kartik\daterange\DateRangePicker;
use kartik\daterange\MomentAsset;
use yii\web\JqueryAsset;

JqueryAsset::register(this);
MomentAsset::register(this);
...
echo DateRangePicker::widget([ 
    'model' => $model, 
    ...
]);
```

Since I switched to twig templating, I ended up with the following code in my view:

```
{{ use('kartik/daterange/DateRangePicker') }}
{{ use('kartik/daterange/MomentAsset') }}
{{ use('yii/web/JqueryAsset') }}
{{ register_jquery_asset() }}
{{ register_moment_asset() }}
...
{{ date_range_picker_widget({ 
    'model': model, 
    ...
   }) }}
```

Comment: `Use of undefined constant this - assumed 'this'` however jquery is not including in my view using your suggested method.