# Adding jQuery script to a single view in Yii2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

I am working on the basic template of Yii2. I have got a jQuery script `views/usuario/js/create.js` that it's only going to be used in one view `views/usuario/create.php`.

I'd prefer not to use ...

```
public $jsOptions = array(
    'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD
);
```

... in `assets/AppAsset.php` in order to mantain loading of scripts at the end of the page.

`create.js` it's only needed in the `create.php` view so I'd prefer to load it just for the create.php view.

So I've tried unsuccessfuly to follow [ippi's instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600383/referenceerror-is-not-defined-yii2/21644899#21644899)
Firebug keeps throwing me this error:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
http://www.example.com/usuario/js/create.js
Line 1
```

I guess there could be a problem with the route param of ...

```
$this->registerJsFile('js/create.js');
```

... but I can't find it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`registerJsFile()` needs an url, you should simply publish (make it web accessible) your file before registering it, e.g. :

```
$pub = Yii::$app->assetManager->publish(__DIR__ . '/create.js');
$this->registerJsFile($pub[1], ['depends' => ['yii\web\JqueryAsset']]);
```

Or you could create an asset bundle and registering it in your view.

Read more about [`publish()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetmanager.html#publish()-detail) and [`registerJsFile()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#registerJsFile()-detail).

Comment: Thank you @soju. That was the key.

Comment: Tried to register my asset bundle in my view but had no luck.$this -> registerAssetBundle('FileInputAsset') said there was no such a class. I'd prefer not to load FileInputAsset directly in AppAsset but in my view. Wheter you can give me a quick answer or not ... a lot of thanks for the former solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$this->registerScriptFile('views/usuario/js/create.js');`

Comment: It does not work. May be this function is for Yii but not for Yii2.